# Labels not showing up on Force Visualization

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, force-layout

I am making a force layout in d3.  The code attaches the labels to the svg and I can see them in the elements tab in the inspector.

But they don't show up on the screen.

The labels are present but for some reason they are not showing up. When you go to the elements tab in the inspector you can see them.  I am thinking maybe it is a css issue or there needs to be a value attached for placement of the labels. The tool tips work but I need the actual labels to be there all the time.

```
***********************JS*********************

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

// Add "forces" to the simulation here
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-30))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10).strength(0.9))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }));


d3.json("data/force.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // Add lines for every link in the dataset
    // Basic tooltips

    var tip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .html(function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });
        svg.call(tip)

    var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
            .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return 
Math.sqrt(d.value); });

    // Add circles for every node in the dataset
    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .on("mouseover", tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", tip.hide)
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended)
            );

    node.append("label")
            .text(function(d) { return d.id });

    // Attach nodes to the simulation, add listener on the "tick" 
event
    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    // Associate the lines with the "link" force
    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.links)

    // Dynamically update the position of the nodes/links as time 
passes
    function ticked() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }
});

// Change the value of alpha, so things move around when we drag a 
node
function dragstarted(d) {
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

// Fix the position of the node that we are looking at
function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

// Let the node do what it wants again once we've looked at it
function dragended(d) {
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}

***********************CSS*********************
svg {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
 border: black solid 2px;
}

.links line {
 stroke: #999;
 stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1.5px;
}


text {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: black;
}

.node label {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: black;
}

.node text {
 font: 10px sans-serif;
 color: black;
}

***********************HTML*********************
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgithub.com/Caged/d3- 
tip/master/examples/example-styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>
<svg width="1400" height="900"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/tool-tip.js"></script>
```

Comment: I believe you want svg `text` elements, but you'll have to append the `text` elements to a `g` rather than each circle (as `node.append()` is adding an element to each circle).